# How to read multiple curly brackets with json in python?

Tags: python, json

I need a way to read multiple curly brackets in python. I have a test json that has multiple layers of curly brackets and I need to get to the deepest layer. My test json: [my json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4E6k.png) (I need it to return "name". My code isn't working, but this is what it looks like (not all of it, just the important parts.)

```
import json 
    
with open(args.mc_path + "launcher_profiles.json", "r+") as profiles:
    data = json.load(profiles)

test = data["profiles": { "053abfb0fb7451c291b9149ea7df88c8": {"name"}}]
print(test)
```

Comment: You need to use the standard Python dictionary way to access data, in your case `data["profiles"]["053abfb0fb7451c291b9149ea7df88c8"]["name"]`

Comment: Part of building a [mre] is eliminating details that aren't actually pertinent to the question. The fact that your data structure was created by loading a JSON file doesn't change how you access it -- if you had that data hardcoded in your Python source code and it was never represented as JSON at all, the access method would still be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index on nested dictionaries multiple times to get the nested value.
In your case that would look like:

```py
test = data["profiles"]["053abfb0fb7451c291b9149ea7df88c8"]["name"]
```